# Difference between a relay and a fault passage indicator (FPI)?

Tags: relay, protection, fault, power-grid

What is the difference between a fault passage indicator (FPI) and a relay (for example relay 50, 51, 67N) ? Are they the same thing?

Comment: I don't know what a fault passage indicator is, but the fact that it has a fairly specific-sounding name would indicate to me that it's probably something more special-purpose than a relay. And the fact that a relay is not something I would generally call an "indicator" of any type.

Comment: A fault indicator is a device that clamps on to a distribution conductor and if current exceeds a set threshold it will give indication (visual or via radio when interrogated).  See [this](https://selinc.com/solutions/fault-indicators-and-sensors/).  Saves time when linemen are out looking for a fault location.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fault passage indicator is used by electric utilities to visually indicatd (such as by a mechanical flag) that a fault has occurred on a transmission line. A relay is an electrical switch that can be actuated  by some sort of signal such as AC or DC voltage. The two devices are unrelated although, perhaps, a relay could be used as part of an FPI.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's clear!